# How do skip cucumber steps?

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I have a requirement to skip the rest of the steps of the test, based on the output of the previous/current step.

How do I do that with cucumber? I am using cucumber with ruby along with gherkin.

Basically, I want to check if the element in an application in dashboard is enabled, the test should proceed only when it is, else it should skip the rest of the test steps.

I tried using `AfterStep` in hooks `next if` condition and `scenario.skip_invoke!` but cucumber says it has `undefined method`

Can anyone help me understand about how do I achieve skipping the test?

Comment: Possible to add step definition code? Might help out. There is this method which you could use [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/RbSupport/RbWorld#skip_this_scenario-instance_method)

Comment: @DanielFintinariu Thanks man! This works. You saved me....! Can you post this as an answer and I ll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `skip_this_scenario` method.

Information on this can be found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/RbSupport/RbWorld#skip_this_scenario-instance_method)

Comment: Hey just in case, have you worked on cucumber reports in jenkins? I am currently having trouble with reports that does not reflect the status of the tests that has failed in the first attempt but passed in re-run.

Comment: Sorry, not that familiar. I'm sure you can find the info you need, either here or by googling. Cheers